# Cannot include wysiwyg.js script in Jade with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, wysiwyg

While trying to create a rich text editor, I cannot seem to add the js script for the buttons and form. Right now, most of the functions are inlined in the jade pages, but that is quite unelegant.

I have a layout.jade file:

```
doctype html
html
    head
body
    header
    section.content
    block content
```

And the create.jade script, where I want the rich text editor:

```
extends ../layout

block content
    script(type='text/javascript', src='./css/js/wiz.js')
    form(method="post", action=post ? '/post/edit/' + post.id : '/post/create', onload="iFrameOn()")
        ul
         p
         input#title(name="title", placeholder="Title", value=post ? post.title : '', autocomplete='off')
         p
         #wysiwyg_cp(style="padding:8px; width:700px")
             input(type="button", onClick="iBold();", value="B")
             input(type="button", onClick="richTextField.document.execCommand(\"underline\",false,null);", value="U")
         p
         textarea#blogPostBody(style="display:none", name="blogPostBody", placeholder="Blog post text", rows="20", cols="50")
         iframe#richTextField(name="richTextField", contentEditable="true", onLoad="richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';")
                if(post)
                    | #{post.body}
                else
                    | &#09
         p
         input(onClick="javascript:submit_form();", type="button", name="myBtn", value="Save")
```

The structure of the project looks like:

```
Proj
- css
 -- js
  --- wiz.js
- middleware
- node_modules
- public
- routes
- views
 -- post
  --- create.jade
 -- layout.jade
 -- home.jade
 -- login.jade
- app.js
- package.json
```

When trying to open the create section of my blog, I get the following error message, as can be seen in the image below:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

See chrome stack: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyHs2.png

The wiz.js file looks like this:

```
function iFrameOn() { richTextField.document.designMode = 'On'; }

function iBold() { richTextField.document.execCommand("bold",false,null); }

function iUnderline(){ richTextField.document.execCommand("underline",false,null); }

function iItalic(){ richTextField.document.execCommand("italic",false,null); }

function iImage() {
    var imgSrc = prompt("EnterImageLocation", '');
    if(imgSrc!=null) {
        richTextField.document.execCommand("insertimage",false,imgSrc);
    }
}

function submit_form() {
    var theForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
    theForm.elements("myTextArea").value = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML;
    theForm.submit();
}
```

I have also tried adding

```
 app.set('view options', {locals:{scripts:['wiz.js']}});
```

and/or adding

```
app.use(express.static("./css/js"));
```

In the app.js file or in the middleware.
But these did not help. The problem seem to be in the "create.jade" script, when referencing the 'text/javascript' script, because the same error was obtained even when referencing a non-existant js file.

Could anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

[EDIT] SOLUTION that was implemented:

```
script
    include ./../../css/js/wiz.js
```

Comment: After including in the create.jade file, the script loading after the iframe declaration, the first error in Chrme console was gone.

Now, however, I the iFrameOn() function is still not foun from the jade file: 

`iframe#richTextField(name="richTextField", contentEditable="true", onload="iFrameOn();")`
`script(type='text/javascript', src='./../../css/js/wiz.js')`

Comment: Welcome at StackOverflow. Please do not post code snippets in comments; [edit] your question instead (apply to answers as well, please). Do not confound sites at http://stackexchange.com/sites those _are not_ chats! Take a two-minutes [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet of code worked:

`script
        include ./../../css/js/wiz.js`

Answer (score 0):

Express's static middleware will by default mount the files to the root. So, if you include the middleware as above, the `wiz.js` file will be accessible at **"/wiz.js"** when your server's running -- this is the path you should put in the src attribute of your script tag in the jade file, not the local path (since local files are not accessible to the client unless they are served). If you want to change the mountpath (so, for example, that the file will be accessible on **"/js/wiz.js"**, rather than the root), you can add it as a first argument, like below:

```
var localDirectoryPath = "./css/js";
// Or if you happened to want an absolute path
// (though it doesn't make a difference here):
// var localDirectoryPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "css", "js");

app.use("/js", express.static(localDirectoryPath));
```

The temporary solution that you've found (using Jade's `include` function) is merely loading the file's contents on the server (when Jade compiles the template) and inserting the code in between script tags on your page, which works but is certainly not ideal, since it will slow down the initial loading of your HTML, especially as the `wiz.js` file gets bigger.

And I won't even ask why your javascript directory is inside your css directory!

Comment: I tried adding it to the middleware, but didn't get the directory right.

I added the js in the css directory after seeing how it was done in places like the bootstrap libraries. I considered it appropriate there since it handled elements from the UI.

But I will consider a more appropriate place to place the wiz.js file. Thank you for the comment on this!

Comment: So did adding the middleware with the correct path solve the problem? If so, please click the tick to accept my answer. :) And structure is subjective, so if nesting the js folder within the css one makes sense to you, do it. I'd be inclined to put them both on the same level though (and possibly both inside a "public" or "static" directory that shows where you keep your static files, as opposed to the compiled Jade views and other code).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I am using the solution I found, with the inclusion of js. It is simpler, faster, albeit, not for the situation in which the code is used often in different places. But for my needs, where I only use the script in one place, it is the proper solution. So, I ticked that one as the answer. Thank you very much for your help and comments! If I had enough reputation, I'd upvote it!

Comment: Fair enough. If I were you, I'd spend time studying modern JS and HTML standards in greater depth before embarking on a big project though. For example, using the "onClick" attribute is not considered good form in HTML5; one should instead use `addEventListener` in javascript (or an equivalent jQuery function like `on` or `click`). Good luck!

Comment: thank you for the advice! Is there any particular resource you would recommend for this?

Comment: Learning is a process that never stops, I'm still learning myself. There are lots of useful blogs, books, screencasts available online now (or offline if you have a good computing library or money to spend). [Here's](http://jsbooks.revolunet.com/) a collection of free JS books that may be more or less useful, for example.